# Maintaining uptime on heroku

Tags: heroku, uptime

I'm sure this been asked many times before, but I can't find any previous questions here.

We had an outage on our Heroku applications the EU last night. What techniques or strategies can we use to maintain a higher uptime when Heroku has major errors?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution against provider downtime is to be multi-homed. So set up a standby system somewhere else.